# Leaflet Marker Tooltip centered

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet, markers

I want to display the tooltip centered (inside) of the marker.

### Background

I want to display a count for each marker (first -> last) and I've found out I could do that with tooltip (Any better suggestions)

so my marker looks like this now,

```
var marker = L.marker(latlng, {icon: blueIcon}).bindTooltip(feature.properties.count, 
                    {
                permanent: true, 
                direction: 'right'
            });
```

I couldn't find any further documentation on direction `centered` or similar.

The tooltip provides the functionality to see which was the first and last marker however it seems not to be best practice.

So my questions:

- Is there a better solution than tooltip?
- how can I display the count centered in the marker?

## Example

Current:
[image]

wanted:
[image]

(Here I would make the background invis so I could just see the text.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found out you could add `direction: center`.
Ref: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#tooltip-direction

I've solved my problem with [DivIcon](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#divicon)

```
var numberIcon = L.divIcon({
                    className: "number-icon-default",
                    iconSize: [25, 41],
                    iconAnchor: [10, 44],
                    popupAnchor: [3, -40],
                    html: feature.properties.count        
              });
```

with the css like

```
    .number-icon-default
{
    background-image: url("#{request.contextPath}/lib/leaflet/images/marker-icon.png");
    text-align:center;
    color:Black;   
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

## Result

[image]

Comment: If this is't enough you can utilise the fact the Tooltip inherits from [DivOverlay](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#divoverlay) so you can set it `className` option and fiddle the positioning with CSS.

Comment: @TomasVarga it seems fine for now, however getting the tooltip box invisible makes me struggle.

Comment: That's what setting the css class might help with - I'd try to set background-color & border transparent

Comment: ... From my previous dealing with Leaflet I remember there are occassions where class set like this actually sets className of an inner element (so borders on a parent were left untouched), I went with a [DivIcon](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#divicon) then (which can be completely customized)

Comment: @TomasVarga Yes, perfect. DivIcon was the thing i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better solution than tooltip?

Not necessarily "better" (which depends on your exact requirements), but a more simple solution would be to use a Marker Icon with some HTML text in it.

Many Leaflet [plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#markers--renderers) can provide you with such feature, e.g. [Leaflet.extra-markers](https://github.com/coryasilva/Leaflet.ExtraMarkers):

```js
var map = L.map('map').setView([48.86, 2.35], 11);

var redMarker = L.ExtraMarkers.icon({
  number: '42',
  icon: 'fa-number',
  markerColor: 'red',
  shape: 'square',
  prefix: 'fa'
});

L.marker([48.86, 2.35], {
  icon: redMarker
}).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<!-- Leaflet assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-IkGU/uDhB9u9F8k+2OsA6XXoowIhOuQL1NTgNZHY1nkURnqEGlDZq3GsfmdJdKFe1k1zOc6YU2K7qY+hF9AodA==" crossorigin=""></script>

<!-- Leaflet.extramarkers assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-extra-markers@1.0.6/src/assets/css/leaflet.extra-markers.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-extra-markers@1.0.6/src/assets/js/leaflet.extra-markers.js"></script>

<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I wanted to keep it simple without injecting any plugins!